# error calling a php class function

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to call a function in a external php class file

control.php

```
require_once ('../vista/ViewEscola.php');
$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

and this is the external file  ViewEscola.php

```
class A
{
    public function foo()
    {
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo '$this is defined (';
            echo get_class($this);
            echo ")\n";
        } else {
            echo "\$this is not defined.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

it doesn't do anything,

can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', true'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` . And your code is supposed to always find a `$this`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo` try `return` from the function and also pass the variable as an argument of function.Also dont use `$this`.If you are not getting any errors try display errors on with `ini_set('display_errors', true'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Try like

```
require_once ('../vista/ViewEscola.php');
class A
{
    public function foo($arg)
    {
        if (isset($this)) {
            $ret = '$arg is defined (';
            $ret .= get_class($arg);
            $ret .= ")\n";
        } else {
            $ret =  "\$arg is not defined.\n";
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}

$arg = 'Hi';
$a = new A();
$ret = $a->foo($arg);
echo $ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php
    class A
   {
      public function foo()
     {
        if (isset($this)) {
        echo '$this is defined (';
        echo get_class($this);
        echo ")\n";
    } else {
        echo "\$this is not defined.\n";
    }
}
}
  $a = new A();
  $a->foo();
  ?>
```

I have tried executing the above code snippet into a php and it printed "$this is defined (A) "
So might there be issue related to include path for class file into your code snippet

You can identify the error with following code snippet

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>
```